# Eclipse Keyboard Shortcut To List All Classes in Project

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has this awesome thing called a Quick Outline <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. I want something similar but with classes, as I am entering a new project with tons of classes and no clue which source file they come from.

Example: Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and all classes are listed, you start typing it modifies the list, you press enter, it opens that source file.

Does this functionality exist in Eclipse? I looked through the `Keys` menu, couldn't find anything, probably not using the right name for it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: All Types (`Classes`) in **open projects in workspace**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: All Files (java, xml, properties) in **open projects in workspace**

First one in useful in finding classes `ABC`, `XYZ`, `SABC`:

```
public class ABC {

class XYZ { }

static class SABC { }

}
```

Comment: Perfect, I needed `All Types` ... The Resources one are great, but filenames don't always hold the correct class name.

Comment: Only one problem though ... Ctrl+Shift+T with an interior class and it's saying it's not found in the workspace. I tried refreshing ... same error. Any tips?

Comment: @Kevin that's hilarious - 2 seconds after me.

Comment: @Constantin Do you mean the answer or comment? I actually answered prior to your answer.

Comment: Yep, for inner `class` or `static` inner classes this work, you should try this by creating one... Omit Proxy/Anonymous classes!

Comment: Heh harsh, I have over 5000, no but really this project has tons of inner classes which is why I really need something to find them. @kevin i just meant we brought up the same situation at the same time in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to search for class names using wildcards.

This can be used not just for class files but any type of file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> which displays a list of all classes/files which can be filtered.  It saves tons of time.

This shortcut is known as [open resource](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-keybindings.htm).

If you need to search for a class whose name may not match the filename, such as an inner class you can use file search in combination with `class [classname]`.

File Search

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, then click file search and enter `class [yourclasnamehere]`.

File search is very useful, it will search the contents of every file for a supplied token.  I found it so useful I gave the shortcut its own mapping.

Comment: What does the declaration of your inner class look like?  I didn't know anything could be between the `class` and the classname.

Comment: Wait I see, it was a problem with the context of pressing CTRL-H ... I missed your "file search" tab mention.

Comment: @Constantin Gotcha, unfortunately this awesome shortcut does not receive a default mapping, but you can always change that.  I made `CTRL` + `H` go straight to file search.  Make sure its configured to search all files and that it uses case insensitive searching.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late to answer it but would like to add my two cents.
apart from all the answers above one can also use 'Type Hierarchy' in eclipse to list down all the classes alphabetically in a specific project of workspace.

> In left pane select project whose classes you wish to see and press F4
>
> Alternatively, In left pane select project whose classes you wish to
>   see, right click and click on "Open Type Hierarchy"

**select project** and open **Type Hierarchy** or Simply press Shortcut **F4**

[image: ]]

**It will look like below**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl + Shift + H` keys to search for classes.